# Formatting Date issue in R

Tags: r, dplyr, as.date

I have some data that includes dates. Those dates are formatted as such:

```
5/9/17
6/8/17
6/9/18
6/19/19
```

I am attempting to format them so they look as such:

```
2017-05-09
2018-06-08
2018-06-09
2019-06-19
```

My attempt was to convet it like this:

```
table$date_purchased <- format(as.Date(data$date_purchased), "%Y-%b-%d")
```

It returns ugly results looking as such:

```
 [1] "0005-Sep-17" "0006-Aug-18" "0006-Sep-18" NA
```

What am I doing incorrect? I've been following guides online and still getting wonky results.

Comment: `lubridate::mdy("5/9/17")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to pass additional format info to `as.Date()` (to say what is the original date format) and use `%m` instead of `%b` in the output format:

```
table$date_purchased <- format(as.Date(data$date_purchased, "%m/%d/%y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: You don't need the `format` function as you are already asking for the default output of a `Date` object. `as.Date(data$date_purchased,format = "%m/%d/%y")` will give the same output

Comment: @DanielO Thanks, good point! (However, I was not sure as the documentation says: _"If the date string does not specify the date completely, the returned answer may be system-specific."_)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `as.Date` what format your dates are in originally.  Also `%b` will give you the name of the month in words.  Use `%m` to get it in numbers.

```
dates <- c("5/9/17",
"6/8/17",
"6/9/18",
"6/19/19")


format(as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2017-05-09" "2017-06-08" "2018-06-09" "2019-06-19"
```

Comment: Why timezone "EST"?